# Efficient toggle switch

Tags: relay, low-power, efficiency, toggle-switch

Is there a way to circuit a power efficient **toggle** switch controlled by a **SINGLE** button so that absolutely **no current** from the power source is drawn at it's `OFF` state and hopefully but not exactly necessarily, minimal current is drawn on its `ON` state. So far I got this...

[image]

It consumes no power when `OFF` and when pressed the led turns `ON`. I couldn't figure out the turning off bit.

Also don't suggest me to use a button that mechanically toggles. I know that exists, but I don't want to use that.

Additionally I do not want to use normally-closed/double-throw buttons and normally-closed/double-throw relays (which means I only allow the normally-open version of these components). If your solution requires those component variants however, I wouldn't mind for you to post them.

Comment: Just use a mechanical "Push On/Push Off" switch.

Comment: What about a step (or stepper) relay? Is that ruled out as well? Here: http://www.soselectronic.com/?str=1653&article=finder-with-a-step-relay-finder-26-can-be-saved-energy-and-also-installation-costs ; You need the simplest of the configurations.

Comment: @RDrast I'm aware of that solution. But I don't want to use that, that's the challenge.

Comment: @SredniVashtar I would say it's ruled out because I want to be able to create something straight from my inventory, and that looks quite specific.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need two relay: -

[image]

The circuit above also gives you an "off" facility too. Make sure your LED is current limited.

You can also buy a latching relay: -

[image]

Comment: The circuits you provided use two buttons. I only want one button to control both states.

Comment: You are right though in the fact I only need 1 relay in the unfinished circuit I provided.

Comment: Short out the "stop" button to remove its functionality.

Comment: The circuit I provided was UNFINISHED. I want something like a T-flip-flop not a SCR.

Comment: A single pushbutton is supposed to turn on and turn off the connection.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do requires a 4-state asynchronous state machine. For example, a mechanical latching pushbutton implements the 4 states mechanically, in the various positions of its internal parts.

If you are restricting the solution to use non-latching, normally-open SPST switches and relays only, and consume zero power in the standby state, then it is impossible to construct the necessary state machine.

Answer (score 1):

Dave of EEVblog did an episode on a soft latch circuit that looks like it does what you want.  You have to make the capacitor big enough that the circuit doesn't mistakenly oscillate back and forth if you press the button and end up holding it down a fraction of a second too long.  Hope this solves your problem.  Here's the link:

[EEVblog #262 – World’s Simplest Soft Latching Power Switch Circuit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Foc9R0dC2iI)

[image: Schematic Circuit Diagram for EEVblog 262, Worlds Simplest Soft Latching Power Switch Circuit]